# how to resolve a fakepath with google chrome using angular2

Tags: google-chrome, path

I need to get a path from my application with angular2 typescript 
the path that I get is (c:\fakepath\img.png )
I ask if there is any solution 
thanks

Comment: Why don't you just get the fake path? What is the error?

Comment: because google chrome can permit to get a full path for security reason so 
there is no error (however in internet explorer I get a full path)

Answer (score 2):

Below is the example

> ts file

```
upload(file)
 { console.log('file'+':'+file.value) 
   const inputNode = file.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
   console.log(inputNode);
 }
```

In the above function i have  passed file value as a parameter and used javascript replace function to replace "C:\fakepath\" with a blank space

> html file

```
<input  class="file" (click)="file.click()"  type="file" accept="image/*" #file >   

<button mat-raised-button (click)="upload(file)">Upload</button>
```